# jquery tablesorter resizing column width to wrong size

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter, pager

I am having 2 issues with tablesorter.

The first one is that when I change the amount of rows dynamically (with checkboxes) the column widths for the rows in the tbody change to fit the first thead column width.

And the second is, tablesorterpager is not refreshing and loading only 10 rows when it dynamically changes.

Any help would be great.

Here is the link: http://www.greatgulf.com/houses2013/project/edgewood

Comment: Did you already solve this issue?

Comment: No we have not. We are using a checkbox interface beside the table and when you use the checkboxes it screws up the table. We are using tablesorter and pager for this. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) from the code I see. But, I have to apologize in advance since I am not able to do more timely support since I'm still on my sabbatical with limited internet access.

I think the main issue with the checkboxes (not within the table) and the pager is the way the `GG.resetTables` function is set up. I can only assume that function is meant to update/refresh the table. In that case, try initializing tablesorter outside of that `resetTables` function, then within that function just trigger an update. Something like this:

```
var $table = $("table")

    // Initialize tablesorter
    // ***********************
    .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widthFixed: true,
        widgets: ['zebra']
    })

    // initialize the pager plugin
    // ****************************
    .tablesorterPager({
        // pager options here
    });


GG.resetTables = function () {
    $table.trigger('update');
};
```